# read pandas DataFrame element by element

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I wish to read pandas DataFrame element by element, but it seems below code doesn't work!

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"B": [5,6,7]})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

for row in df.iterrows():
    print row['A'], row['B']
```

What's the right way to access it element by element?

Comment: Do you just want to print it or actually DO something with it or to it?  E.g. if you want to apply a function to every element, see ```applymap()```

Answer (score 1):

Use `at` and `iat` detailed [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting)

> Since indexing with [] must handle a lot of cases (single-label
>   access, slicing, boolean indexing, etc.), it has a bit of overhead in
>   order to figure out what you’re asking for. If you only want to access
>   a scalar value, the fastest way is to use the at and iat methods,
>   which are implemented on all of the data structures.
>
> Similarly to loc, at provides label based scalar lookups, while, iat
>   provides integer based lookups analogously to iloc

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"B": [5,6,7]})
df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)

for row in df.index:
    print df['A'][row],df['B'][row]
```

Output:

```
2 5
3 6
4 7
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the following works with `iterrows`:

```
>>> for _, row in df.iterrows():
        print row.A, row.B
2 5
3 6
4 7
```